# CLion finds a problem with CMakeLists.txt for importing a library but it works well by command line

Tags: c, cmake, clion

When I use CMake with the terminal, I have no problems at all.
However, when I try to use CLion, SDL_image isn't found anymore...

Here is the error message of CLion:

> **CMake Error at**
> /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164
>
> (message): **Could NOT find SDL2_image (missing: SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES
> SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS)**

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(ProjectName C)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(main.c)
target_link_libraries(main ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES})
```

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe CLion uses different values for CMake variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem !
CLion uses a different version of CMake (3.17), however I use the version 3.19.
I changed the CLion CMake executable in the preferences (Build, Exec... -> Toolchains).
A warning tells me that CMake versions beyond 3.17.x are not supported. But it seems to work well.